# Writing a system for User Accounts

Tags: mysql, profiles, accounts

I am building my own blogging website from scratch (instead of using WordPress or Drupal). I have the articles set up and stored in databases and the website runs queries on the databases to display the content.

How do I write a system for users to register with the site, edit personal details and post comments on the articles? I have never done something like this before and my knowledge of PHP and mySQL is quite fresh.

Comment: Writing a blogging engine is the new 'hello world'!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to read "[Head First PHP & MySQL](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Foreilly.com%2Fcatalog%2F9780596006303&ei=Iej2SsUdkvfgBpbGsOYD&usg=AFQjCNFXw2rdOEfgwhTniEchYZhwabSwng&sig2=0LQlHD6IXm0SGek18lmECA) " . it gives you a good way to start building a website .

Answer (score 0):

Without any PHP sepcifics.

If you want to do it from scratch a basic approach would be to have a separate table for users and have the table linked from other tables where you need a record to be associated with that user, e.g. have user_id in the posts table to point to the author of the post.
Then you'll need a registration form of some kind, pereferably with captcha to guard against spam bots.
It is also a common practice to hash passwords before putting them into the database.
You will also need to use a session mechanism to keep track of logged in users, I suppose PHP provides some session mechanism.
[Commons security threats](http://www.securityfocus.com/infocus/1864) for web applications may be a consideration as well.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a `user` table and a `articles` table.
The user table must have a field for the md5'hashed password (google PHP md5), username and ID.
The Articles table must have a field for the heading/name, the ID of the user that wrote it and a field for the text (article itself).

You can also add a Comment option, but I think that could be too much for a php newb.

Have a look at mysql_real_escape_string, because when php-newbies write mysql/php apps, it often results in "Sql-Injections". That means that a user could manipulate your database or even take over the whole server via your application.